# How do you obtain and use BlockBlobAsyncClient to upload a large file to azure blob storage?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to use the BlockBlobAsyncClient to upload a large file in the most efficient way. I was trying with the normal BlockBlobClient sending the chunks using an ExecutorService and then commiting the blocklist but I'm always ending up wit a file of the correct size but broken and unusable.

Checking the documentation I realized that the latest sdk has the BlockBlobAsyncClient and I want to use it because it seems like a better fit for my use case but I haven't found any examples whatsoever so I'm a little bit lost on how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blockblobasyncclient?view=azure-java-stable), there's for example [public Mono upload(Flux data, long length)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blockblobasyncclient.upload?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_specialized_BlockBlobAsyncClient_upload_reactor_core_publisher_Flux_java_nio_ByteBuffer__long_):

```
client.upload(data, length).subscribe(response ->
     System.out.printf("Uploaded BlockBlob MD5 is %s%n",
         Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(response.getContentMd5())));
```

Comment: Is technically correct, I found my problem was in an existing code that did some file splitting incorrectly.